# Jboss4 inside OSGI

Tags: jboss, osgi

Is it possible to run Jboss 4.2.3 as a bundle inside OSGI container? What would be the challenges associated with it?

For those who cares, I am looking at running dcm4chee inside OSGI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While not impossible it would be incredibly hard, a simpler alternative would be to embed OSGi inside JBoss, see:

http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-framework-launching-and-embedding.html
and
[Programmatically Start OSGi (Equinox)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673406/programatically-start-osgi-equinox)
and
http://njbartlett.name/2011/03/07/embedding-osgi.html

http://www.dcm4che.org/jira/browse/DCM-308 Looks like they're adding support to make the Jars valid bundles - couldn't you just work out the dependencies and deploy these to an OSGi framework?  OSGi has support for JMX and JNDI.

Unless there are huge dependencies on JBoss' internals, I'd suggest the second option, but beware of Class.forName usage and other non-osgi-friendly code.

Comment: Wow, i really would like if they did that. Unfortunately that bug seems to be kind of stale. I'm going to nudge it.

Comment: Also I think we need dcm4chee (double ee) to be osgi-fied.

Answer (score 1):

I logged the [bug](http://www.dcm4che.org/jira/browse/DCM-308) specifically for the dcm4che (note 1 e) toolkits, not the dcm4chee war. I would suggest logging a new issue for the dcm4chee assembly. However, making the dcm4che toolkit components osgi bundles would likely be a required step in the direction of getting dcm4chee to run in an osgi container.