# JNDI resources not available for Gemini Blueprint running in Tomcat 9 (working in Bundle Activator)

Tags: spring, jndi, eclipse-gemini

I have an older Web-Application using Eclipse RAP 3.0 with Equinox OSGI-Container and Gemini Blueprint 1.0.2.

I can define my JDNI Values in server.xml
link them in context.xml and use them in my web.xml.

In my launch.ini i use the parent classloader fwk so the JNDI configuration is passed to the OSGI-Container.

My Application-Bundles can read those values for example in Bundle-Activator:

```
String xxx= InitialContext.doLookup("java:comp/env/xxx"); or
String xxx= new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env/xxx");
```

Some Bundle-Configuration is done via Gemini Blueprint xml files and SpringConfiguration Java classes.

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="xxx" jndi-name="java:comp/env/xxx" />
```

This part is not working and i get following error

```
Error creating bean with name 'xxx': Invocation of init method failed;
nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException:
Name [java:comp/env/xxx] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [java:comp].
```

I get the same Error when i use Spring-Java-Configuration which is invoked from gemini blueprint xml. Then statements like new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env/xxx") don't work and i get the same exception.

I think it has to to with the classloaders that are different for Bundle-Activator-Code and Gemini BlueprintExtender Thread but in can't figure it out how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I found a Solution that i can use.

If i Move my JNDI-Lookups from xml into my Spring-Configuration-class then i can change the clasloader in init like this:
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(this.getClass().getClassLoader());

After that i my Lookups work fine.

i found that solution here

[Can Spring Boot be used with OSGi? If not, any plans to have an OSGi Spring Boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30881786/can-spring-boot-be-used-with-osgi-if-not-any-plans-to-have-an-osgi-spring-boot).