# What is the purpose and usage of class EclipseStarter?

Tags: java, eclipse

I gone through the javadoc for [EclipseStarter](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/runtime/adaptor/EclipseStarter.html) class. 
But did not find the explanation much useful.
Can somebody tell me the exact purpose and usage of this class.

Answer (score 3):

It's used for starting the Eclipse/OSGi framework from within a "normal" java application.  See [How to run an OSGi framework within usual java-code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/904050/how-to-run-an-osgi-framework-within-usual-java-code)